# Titlesec colored chapter accent reproduced in KOMA script

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, titlesec

I am using this https://github.com/derric/cleanthesis template, but its combining titlesec and KOMA script which I would like to avoid.

Heres an example of the chapter style:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}\sectfont}%
  {\vspace{-8em}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%
  [\phantomsection]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span two lines}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way I can reproduce the colored line and chapter number with chapter name linebreak using only KOMA script?

Comment: What should happen if the number has two or three digits?

Comment: Hm good question, for my case its not going to be more than one digit so esdd answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following helps:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example
\usepackage{hyperref}

\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{cyan}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{cyan}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1sp
]{chapter}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {%
      \parbox[b][\ht\strutbox]{\textwidth}{%
        \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#3}%
        \makebox[3em][r]{%
          \hfill
          #2%
        }%
      }%
    }{\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% <- original definition for other levels
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \textcolor{ctcolorchapterline}{\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}%
  \quad
  {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\textcolor{ctcolorchapternum}{\thechapter}}%
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A test chapter with a long title that will span two lines}
\lipsum[4]
\chapter{Chapter with short title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this suggestion is limited to one digit numbers (like your MWE).

---

**Update regarding the usage `appendixprefix=true`**

As mentioned in your comment below you want to set `appendixprefix=true`. So I assume that you want to use the default layout for chapter titles in appendix. Then you have to change the redefinition of `\chapterformat` to

```
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \IfUsePrefixLine{%
    \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot\enskip}%
  }{%
    \textcolor{ctcolorchapterline}{\rule[-5pt]{2pt}{5cm}}%
    \quad
    {\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\textcolor{ctcolorchapternum}{\thechapter}}%
  }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a problem with appendix chapters when I use this and `\appendix` with `appendixprefix=true` for my documentclass, do you happen to know how to fix this?

Comment: @voiDnyx See my updated answer. If it does not solve your issue, then please ask a follow up question and explain what the desired layout for chapters in appendix is. Maybe `\chapterlineswithprefixformat` must be redefined too.

Comment: Im sorry, its working perfectly fine without the appendixprefix option. I had the wrong idea that option was responsible for sections starting with letters. Turns out its for something completely different :)